# Div overflow with scrollbar but no resize option

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am working with a parent div and a child div. The child div needs to be able to resize w/ scrollbar, but any overflow outside the parent div needs to either be hidden altogether or with a scrollbar but no resize option. I included a link to the code I have been working on in JSFiddle. I have tried overflow: hidden, overflow: auto, and overflow: scroll for the parent div and nothing works. No matter what (even for overflow:hidden) that parent div has the resize dragging icon option in the bottom right which is exactly what I do not want. How can I have a resizable child div inside a parent div that is not resizable?

https://jsfiddle.net/9ba54kvp/1/#&togetherjs=4g2SH54efU

PARENT DIV = .tm

CHILD DIV = .overflow

```
.tm {
    position: absolute;
    top: 8%;
    left: 36%;
    resize: both;
    right: 33%;
    bottom: 50%;
    border-radius: 15px;
    padding: 20px;
    background-color: white;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    overflow:auto;
    max-height:initial;
}
.overflow {
        overflow: scroll;
    }
```

**Screenshot of what I have (parent resize in red circle):**

[image]

**Picture of what I want (no resize option in parent div):**

[image]

Comment: Did you try `resize: none;` at line 89 ? Instead of `resize: both;`.

Comment: That did the trick! thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Just remove `resize:both` from the element, just after `<div class="tm">`